# Read a value of a field from a property file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, properties

I have a file called config.properties and I would like to read the value of a field from this file using shell script.

This particular file is available in path /u/application/run/config.properties.

Contents of this file :

```
resource=/Services
Environment=DEV.
```

I would like to read the value of the variable "Environment" which is DEV and assign it to a variable.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

If that is literally the files contents and you can count on that format of contents being consistent and don't need to worry about shell metacharacters (like `*`, or `[`, etc.) in the values then you should be able to just `source /u/application/run/config.properties` and then use `$Environment`.

Comment: Thanks, the contents of the file may vary. There could be several lines added to it or removed.